# How to draw node on demand in JavaFX / custom paint

Tags: java, image, swing, javafx

I am drawing thousands of images from the database. User can scroll over them (like in maps tilesets in Web).

I definitely can't preload images. They should displayed only at the moment they appeared visible on the screen. Also, once they are scrolled out, they should be evicted from memory, they should not kept there forever.

JavaFX forces me to store everything in memory. For example, `Canvas` object holds everything drawn in memory, so I can't use it.

I need a hook into drawing function, like it was in `Swing` `paintComponent`. I would check if image is already loaded and load and draw if not.

Is it possible to simulate the same in JavaFX?

Comment: Please clarify existing questions, instead of posting new questions that are almost identical to the original.